# Accessing local actuator JMX endpoints using VisualVM

Tags: jmx, visualvm, spring-boot-actuator

``I am trying to access the JMX actuator endpoints using jvisualvm.

I have done the following

- used the actuator service sample project (`gs-actuator-service-complete`)
- added property `spring.jmx.enabled=true`
- set the following Java options in the `build.gradle` file

`bootRun {
      jvmArgs = ["-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false"]
}`

- started the app using `./gradlew bootrun`
- launched `jvisualvm`
- tried `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi/://localhost:9001/jmxrmi` and `service:jmx:remote+http://localhost:9001` in the Add JMX Connection dialog.
- the following pictures show the Add JMX Connection dialog and error

[JMX Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQaoI.jpg)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjXtT.jpg)

In particular

- is there anything else that needs to be configured?
- what is the correct value to put into the Add JMX Connection dialog to allow me to see the `actuator/metrics` and other endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install 'VisualVM-MBeans' plugin, since the data are exported as MBeans. Once you have 'VisualVM-MBeans' plugin installed, just open actuator service sample project from VisualVM and switch to 'MBeans' tab. Spring MBeans can be accessed under org.springframework.boot on left tree.